# Trying to open .dpk file in C++Builder does nothing, no message, no nothing?

Tags: c++builder

I have a component that has a D11.dpk file that I'm trying to open it via open project in C++Builder 11.3;  I select it, and nothing happens. No message, the welcome screen still sitting there, the project menu still disabled like no project is open.

How can I tell what is going on?  Is this supposed to work or not, from what I read it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.dpk` file is a [**Delphi** package project](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Package_Source_File_(*.dpk)). A **C++Builder** package project is a `.bpk` file instead. C++Builder cannot open Delphi projects, it can only compile [Delphi unit source files](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Source_File) that are added to C++ projects. To compile a `.dpk` project, you must use Delphi instead of C++Builder. However, most editions of C++Builder include a [command-line Delphi compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler), which can compile `.dpk` projects.

Comment: Can you convert a .dpk to .bpk somehow - do they include a utility?

Comment: Do you know the command line to add to the answer?

Comment: @user3161924 there is no conversion utility.